# Setting up logging on buckets in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Trying to set up logging on a GCS bucket.  every time i enter the command to set logging i get the error below.  **"Command exception: "logging" command does not support "file://" URLs. did you mean to usea gs:// URL?"**   is it my test logs bucket that has the error or my bucket covered by the logging command?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think your issue is you're passing the literal `[-o logs]`. You need to either remove it completely, or remove the brackets and pick a value for the log prefix.

Comment: After some time fooling around with it someone pointed that out to me.  thanks for the reply.   gotta get more sleep when i do this.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error when following this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage.
Solution was simple. I forgot my 2 forward slashes: `//` after `gs:`

Wrong commands:

```
$ gsutil mb gs:tony-project-123
$ gsutil defacl set public-read gs:tony-project-123
```

Right commands:

```
$ gsutil mb gs://tony-project-123
$ gsutil defacl set public-read gs://tony-project-123
```